# Error provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, distribution, profile, provisioning

I successfully built my app for distribution, but now, it does`t build anymore for debug on my iPhone device. Xcode try to run on my distribution profile instead of my developer profile. If I change the bundle identifier for what it was before, when I build I get a Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile. I changed the code signing identity back to my iPhone developer profile, and still fails with the iPhone distribution error.
Am I missing something here?

P.S. I already cleaned all targets, and it didn`t help.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your Project settings and *also* your Target settings, are they both set to use the Developer profile?

My guess is you didn't change the Target settings to use the developer profile.  I normally just set the target to automatic and then it defaults to what the Project settings are.